# Quartz scheduling problem

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

In my web app i have to retreive the dates on which reminders are to be sent from a database and send Sms and  email reminders on those dates.Can anyone tell me how to do this?I have to use quartz scheduler for the same.However I am using quartz scheduler for the first time.

Comment: You'll get better results if you ask a specific question and give more details. What have you already tried, what are you stuck on etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a set of [Cron type Quartz triggers](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorials/crontrigger.html).

EG: Make a daily one that selects all the reminders for a given day (create a view with them). Then use a hourly one to process the reminders for that day - this will help you distribute the workload in 24hours. You can go further on up to your desired granularity for events (quarters, minutes).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial on how to use Quartz: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/index.html